# jScrollPane how do i remove the mousewheel functionalitie

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane

Whenever my mouse enters jScrollPane and i use my mousewheel i want the scrollbar of the browser itself to scroll instead of the one on in jScrollPane.

So when i'm scrolling down in my browser with my mousewheel and i pass over the jScrollPane with my mouse it shouldn't stop scrolling down in the browser.

Why? I am using a horizontal scrollbar in my jScrollPane and i want my mousewheel for vertical scrolling only.

Hope this makes sense and isn't to vague.

Comment: See this link, it might be possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803375/how-to-disable-scrolling-from-mouse-wheel-in-a-jscrollpane-header

Comment: @AhsanRathod : it seems there are 2 jScrollPane : one in Java and one in jQuery/JS. The link you gave is tagged "Java", this one "Javascript" ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mhh.. it does not seem jScrollPane has something to enable/disable mousewheel, but you can find 2 solutions I think:

1. Do not include the jquery mousewheel plugin (that is optional for jScrollPane)
2. Unbind the "mousewheel" event of the container with jQuery AFTER having used the 
   `$(**yourcontainer**).jScrollPane();` like that :

   ```
   $(**yourcontainer**).unbind('mousewheel');
   ```

**Edit :**

Here is the pluggin code that bind the mousewheel event :

```
 $container.bind(
   'mousewheel',
   function (event, delta) {
     delta = delta || (event.wheelDelta ? event.wheelDelta / 120 : (event.detail) ? -event.detail/3 : 0);
     initDrag();
     ceaseAnimation();
     var d = dragPosition;
     positionDrag(dragPosition - delta * mouseWheelMultiplier);
     var dragOccured = d != dragPosition;
     return !dragOccured;
   }
 );
```

And here the description of the plugin and its config :

```
 * @name jScrollPane
 * @type jQuery
 * @param Object        settings        hash with options, described below.
 *                                                              scrollbarWidth  -       The width of the generated scrollbar in pixels
 *                                                              scrollbarMargin -       The amount of space to leave on the side of the scrollbar in pixels
 *                                                              wheelSpeed              -       The speed the pane will scroll in response to the mouse wheel in pixels
 *                                                              showArrows              -       Whether to display arrows for the user to scroll with
 *                                                              arrowSize               -       The height of the arrow buttons if showArrows=true
 *                                                              animateTo               -       Whether to animate when calling scrollTo and scrollBy
 *                                                              dragMinHeight   -       The minimum height to allow the drag bar to be
 *                                                              dragMaxHeight   -       The maximum height to allow the drag bar to be
 *                                                              animateInterval -       The interval in milliseconds to update an animating scrollPane (default 100)
 *                                                              animateStep             -       The amount to divide the remaining scroll distance by when animating (default 3)
 *                                                              maintainPosition-       Whether you want the contents of the scroll pane to maintain it's position when you re-initialise it - so it doesn't scroll as you add more content (default true)
 *                                                              tabIndex                -       The tabindex for this jScrollPane to control when it is tabbed to when navigating via keyboard (default 0)
 *                                                              enableKeyboardNavigation - Whether to allow keyboard scrolling of this jScrollPane when it is focused (default true)
 *                                                              animateToInternalLinks - Whether the move to an internal link (e.g. when it's focused by tabbing or by a hash change in the URL) should be animated or instant (default false)
 *                                                              scrollbarOnLeft -       Display the scrollbar on the left side?  (needs stylesheet changes, see examples.html)
 *                                                              reinitialiseOnImageLoad - Whether the jScrollPane should automatically re-initialise itself when any contained images are loaded (default false)
 *                                                              topCapHeight    -       The height of the "cap" area between the top of the jScrollPane and the top of the track/ buttons
 *                                                              bottomCapHeight -       The height of the "cap" area between the bottom of the jScrollPane and the bottom of the track/ buttons
 *                                                              observeHash             -       Whether jScrollPane should attempt to automagically scroll to the correct place when an anchor inside the scrollpane is linked to (default true)
 * @return jQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but both options are not working for me.

Comment: Mhh.. I really thought it would work. Maybe try to set "wheelSpeed" at 0 when you initialize the pluggin, but I don't think it will fit.

Comment: It works for me only if i include the jquery.mousewheel plugin.